# Multiple laravel 5.5 routes methods showing error

Tags: php, laravel

I have three routes in web.php

```
Route::get('/secondary', 'SecondaryController@show');
Route::get('/primary', 'PrimaryController@show');
Route::get('/nursery', 'NurseryController@show');
```

But when i click on the respective menu link, it presents the first route, others just wont work.
pls what am i doing wrongly, i need help.
this is code for the controllers
**for the nursery controller**

```
public function show($slugs){
     $NurseryPages = NurseryPages::findByURL($slugs);
     return view('nursery.show', ['NurseryPages' =>$NurseryPages]);
}
```

**for the primary controller**

```
 public function show($slugs){
     $PrimaryPages = PrimaryPages::findByURL($slugs);
     return view('primary.show', ['PrimaryPages' =>$PrimaryPages]);
}
```

**for the secondary controller**

```
public function show($slugs)
{
     $SecondaryPages = SecondaryPages::findByURL($slugs);
     return view('secondary.show', ['SecondaryPages' =>$SecondaryPages]);
}
```

it will only work well for the nursery section, but on others it displays error: trying to get object of non-property and refers me back to the nursery.show file
this is the error msg

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
```

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\acadapp\resources\views\secondary\show.blade.php)

```
    <?php echo $__env->make('inc.secondary.navbar', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <b><h3><?php echo $SecondaryPage->title; ?></b></h3>
             <?php echo $SecondaryPage->body; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $__env->make('inc.secondary.footer', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

Comment: "Secondary controller"? But only one controller is used in web.php, PagesController...

Comment: sorry, that was i typo. i've corrected it

Comment: Where is `$slugs`s value?

Comment: In your route secondary, primary, nursery are slug ?

Comment: yea u are not passing the slugs that is y u are getting error.

Comment: the $slug is fro a function in thier respective model classes

Comment: Where do you get this error? Can you give us a stack trace? `Trying to get property of non-object` can mean that `$slugs` isn't filled and that your view is crapping out.

Comment: I have added the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your route like:

```
Route::get('/secondary/{slug}', 'SecondaryController@show');
Route::get('/primary/{slug}', 'PrimaryController@show');
Route::get('/nursery/{slug}', 'NurseryController@show');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i tried that and no diff.